# terraform for kafka configuration

Tags: terraform

I have setup 3 node kafka cluster instances using Terraform on Digital Ocean. Once the servers are provisioned, there are some zookpeeper and server configuration by editing the `zookeeper.properties` and `server.properties`. Should these be done with Terraform or should be done using Configuration management tools like Chef and Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you have configuration management with ansible already established and deployed your ssh keys just use that.
Otherwise use the user_data section in digital oceans droplet to run a script and deploy the configfiles using the script.